# How format text, in a div element, with syntax highlighting using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm using Snippet jQuery Syntax Highlighter.
http://steamdev.com/snippet/

When the text is first displayed, its syntax appears correctly. But when I change the text, the script does not work.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("pre.ruby").snippet("ruby",{style:"neon"});
  })

  //This function remove all #aside child elements, recreate child #code
  //And change text inner #code
  function loadUrl(url) {
var node = dojo.byId("aside");


while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
      node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
}

var aside = document.getElementById('aside');
aside.innerHTML = "<pre id='code' class='ruby'> </pre>";


$("#code").load(url);
$("pre.ruby").snippet("ruby",{style:"neon"});

   }
 </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="aside">
  <pre id="code" class="ruby">
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: You may need to do `$("pre.ruby").snippet("ruby",{style:"neon"});` again after updating the contents.

Comment: I do that, look last Javascript line.

Comment: please re-add the working link example for this: Look demo: http://predoff.github.com/Algorithms/

Answer (score 1):

`load()` isn't completing before you apply syntax highlighting the second time. You should move the syntax call to `load()`'s completion callback.

```
$("#code").load(url, function() {
    $("pre.ruby").snippet("ruby",{style:"neon"});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. With this way, 'load()' run first then apply the syntax highlighting, right?

Comment: Correct, syntax highlighting only happens once `load()` has finished its job.