# Syntax Highlighting using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I created a logger window for my Django website - basically just grabs lines from a .txt log file that my views.py python logger creates and displays them in a popup window.  The code I created to do this grabs lines from the log file every second and uses javascript to write them to a `<span>` element.  I want to be able to color code the messages based on the message level (ERROR = red, WARNING = yellow, etc) but can't seem to figure it out.

**EDIT**

I was able to color the first `WARNING` message but am not sure how to get it to color all of them.

The html/javascript code to create the log window looks like this:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
      <h4 class="text-center">Log Messages</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="content" id="logtext">
        <font face="courier">
          <span id="show" class='value'></span>
        </font>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function saveLogs(data){
      sessionStorage.setItem("logs",data.message);
    }
      $(document).ready(
        function() {
          setInterval(function() {
            Dajaxice.InterfaceApp.getLogs(saveLogs);
            var logs = sessionStorage.getItem("logs");
            document.querySelector('.content .value').innerText = logs;

            $("div:contains('WARNING')").each(function () {
              $(this).html($(this).html().replace("WARNING", "<span class='red'>WARNING</span>"));
            });
          }, 1000);
        });
  </script>
</div>        
</body>
```

The Dajaxice calls this python function:

```
def getLogs(request):
  fname = log_path
  with open(fname,"r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
  lines = lines[-1000:]
  return json.dumps({'message':lines})
```

The log window currently looks like this:
[image]

and I want to be able to color code the messages based on the level.  I've tried a couple things ([this](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/search-highlight/), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414773/how-format-text-in-a-div-element-with-syntax-highlighting-using-javascript)) but no luck.

Comment: So loop through each line and look for (WARNING) or (ERROR) or (INFO) and set the color.

Comment: @epascarello I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: It is trivial to do the same thing as you did for WARNING, give it a try and then ask a question if you can't get it

Comment: `<span class="red">` ...urp... how about `<span class="log_warning">`? — that is, a class that is meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks the log messages have a fix and simple format, a string replace on the whole log could be used, without the JQuery part:

```
document.querySelector('.content .value').innerHTML = colorize(logs);

function colorize(logs) {
   return logs.replace("(WARNING)", "(<span class='red'>WARNING</span>)");
}
```